# Styles Broken After AJAX .load() Page Navigation

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I built a wordpress site using the [chatbot theme](https://www.quantumcloud.com/products/themes/chatbot-theme/) by [QuantumCloud](https://www.quantumcloud.com/), and I wanted to ajaxify it in the sense of page navigation without page refresh (dynamic page loading).  I have implemented a solution that is mostly working, but which comes with a caveat that I'm struggling to figure out.  When I follow internal links on the site, the desired content is correctly loaded into the targeted div without any page refresh, but at least some of the CSS styling, and potentially also certain JS handlers and listeners, break (dynamically loaded content width is much smaller, parallax effects like mouse tracking and scroll effects on background images are broken, etc).  I'm looking for a solution that either prevents that breakage, or if the breakage is inevitable, that allows me to re-implement the relevant styles and/or handlers/listeners after loading the new content.

Here's my setup:

In the child theme (/wp-content/themes/chatbot-theme-child/), I setup assets/js directory with the following files:

1. [jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js](http://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/raw/v1.3/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js)
   I made one modification to this script for compatibility with later versions of jQuery.  I changed "$.browser.msie" to "$.support.msie" in that script
2. ajaxify-chatbot-theme.js (inspired by [this tutorial](https://deluxeblogtips.com/how-to-ajaxify-wordpress-theme/))

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    var $mainContent = $( ".floating-content" ),
        siteUrl = "https://" + top.location.host.toString(),
        url = '',
        $ajaxSpinner = $( ".loader" );

    $( document ).delegate( "a[href^='" + siteUrl + "']", "click", function() {
        location.hash = this.pathname;
        return false;
    } );

    $( ".search-field" ).submit( function( e ) {
        location.hash = "?s=" + $( ".search-field" ).val();
        e.preventDefault();
    } );

    $( window ).bind( "hashchange", function() {
        url = window.location.hash.substring( 1 );

        if ( !url ) {
            return;
        }

        var finalUrl = url + " .floating-content";

        $mainContent.load( finalUrl, function() {
            $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn();
            $mainContent.animate( { opacity: '0' } );
            history.replaceState( null, null, url );
            $mainContent.animate( { opacity: '1' } );
            $ajaxSpinner.fadeOut();
        } );
    } );

    $( window ).trigger( "hashchange" );
} );
```

To register the scripts with the WordPress theme, I appended the following to the functions.php of the chatbot child theme:

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    $url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/";
    wp_enqueue_script( "hash-change", "{$url}jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js", array( "jquery" ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( "ajaxify-chatbot-theme", "{$url}ajaxify-chatbot-theme.js", array( "hash-change" ), '', true );
}
```

The result of the above steps is the behaviour I described in the first paragraph, where the dynamic content loading works (no page refresh), but styles are broken after navigating.  I have seen many people suggesting using $(this).trigger("create"); within the function passed to .load(), and many people claiming this solution worked for them (I don't understand what that does or why it would or wouldn't work), but it does nothing for me.  I imagine I may need a way to reload broken styles or JS after dynamic content loading, but I'm not sure how to identify what styles or JS have gone missing.  Ideally, I'm wondering if there's a solution that entirely prevents the style breakage in the first place.

As a secondary issue, I also notice that when I click on an internal link, the new dynamically loaded content instantly shows for a split second, then it fades out and shows the spinner graphic and then fades back in.  This makes the content appear to blink, and I'm not entirely sure how to prevent that for a smoother transition.  The spinner and fade out should occur slightly before or at the moment of content change, but instead it seems it's triggering very slightly after the content change, and it's noticeable.

If there's any additional information I should provide, let me know.  I'm also open to solutions along the lines of "yo, I have a way better way to go about ajaxifying wordpress than this."  I'm under pressure to launch this site soon and I feel a little stuck on this, so any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: There is no need to refresh the CSS even if you add HTML manually or dynamically, I believe the styling issue is related to the HTML elements selectors! can you please share your website URL?

Comment: The spinner is being triggered by the Jquery listeners, each time the page is loading/building the page content or making an Ajax request the spinner will be displayed. Solution: you can make a custom Spinner that covers the entire page when you load the content dynamically this way the user won't see any intureption.

Comment: The URL is https://www.strangequark.games/.

Comment: Whether the spinner spans the entire page or not, the issue is that the spinner isn't triggered during the .load() call before the content change occurs, but slightly after.  So you'll see a content change, and then the spinner kicks in with the content opacity dimmed briefly.  It's not an issue of what kind of spinner is being used.

Comment: For the spinner you can use this simple jquery code; $('.loader').show() to display the spinner while the content is retrieving and use $('.loader').hide(), to hide the spinner when your function is done.

Comment: Another question about the styles, can you send a URL with the style correctly displayed? I want to know what's the issue with styles.

Comment: I am not struggling at all with showing and hiding the spinner.  The spinner works.  What I said was not working as desired was more a matter of timing.  The new content dynamically loads seemingly instantly, but the initiation of the reduced opacity of the content area and the showing of the spinner is just a tad late, leading to a blinking effect.

Comment: When you load the site (the URL I gave you), you see all correct styles.  As I described, the styles break after the .load() call in the ajax script.  So to test this, you can go to the link I gave where you will see the homepage, and note how the homepage looks.  Then click on About Us, or any other link, then go back to the homepage by clicking on Home in the top nav.  When you're back on home, note the style change.  The width of the content area is reduced, and the background images in the divs that have them have lost their parallax effects.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the style breaking, all I had to fix in the code I posted in the original post was as follows:

I changed

```
var finalUrl = url + " .floating-content";
```

to

```
var finalUrl = url + " .floating-content .elementor";
```

What this does is stuff the children of .floating-content into .floating-content, rather than stuffing .floating-content into .floating-content, which is what was breaking the styles.

I did mention a couple other issues, namely that parallax effects break after the .load() event and also the issue with the spinner and content animation activating a little late and causing an undesired blinking effect.  I still need to address those issues, but I'm going to go ahead and just make separate posts for those issues.  After I make those posts, I'll link them here in case these issues are of interest to anyone stumbling on this post.